# What is _init() return what is use of init() function?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, methods

**I want to know About what is _init() do in magento?**

```
$this->_initSometext();
```

Comment: See here: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_Abstract.html#_init

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 2 different things.

**`_init`**
`_init` from a collection model sets the model class for the collection items. So each item in the collection will be an instance of the class passed to the `_init` method.

`_init` in a model, sets the resource model class instance used for that model.
`_init` in a resource model class sets the main table and the primary key associated to the resource model.

**`_initSomeText`**
`_initSometext()` has no special meaning. There are a lot of these methods defined all over the code and serve different purposes depending on the class. It's just like any other method in the class. The fact that it starts with `_init` means that probably initializes something.
For example; `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController::_initCategory` reads the request, sets some data for the page layout, and loads the requested category.